# Javascript add letter after specific number of letters in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables, this

I am trying to add a br sign in a input text field if it has more than 5 letters.(while writing)

My Code creates br signs after 5 letters, but it creates for than 1 br sign.

Code:

```
(function(i){
    $('#input' + i).on('keyup', function() {
        if($('#input' + i).val().length > 5) {
            $('#input' + i).val($('#input' + i).val() + '<br>');
        }
    });
}(i))
```

Comment: Don't change the contents of an input while the user is typing. It messes up where the insertion point is and makes for a horrible UX. Format **afterward**, or provide a divided control instead of a single input (and doing that poorly also leads to horrible UX).

Comment: Also note that `keyup` only fires once per key-up action, *not* once per letter added to the input. Pressing and holding a key is one way that the above will break.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there a way to sum up all actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend **not** doing this (seem comments on the question).

But if you really want to, use `input`, not `keyup`, remove previous `<br>` markers you've added, and break up the whole string rather than just appending at the end. See comments:

```js
(function(i) {
  $('#input' + i).on('input', function() {
    // No need to look it up repeatedly, remember the jQuery wrapper for this input
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the value
    var val = $this.val();
    if (val.length > 5) {
      // Remove old <br>s
      val = val.replace(/<br>/g, "");
      // Add new ones
      var result = "";
      while (val) {
        result += val.substring(0, 5);
        val = val.substring(5);
        if (val) {
          result += "<br>";
        }
      }
      // Set the value
      $this.val(result);
    }
  });
}(0))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you recommend to use on input instead of keyup?

Comment: @utdev: Yes, that's why I recommended using `input` instead of `keyup`. See the comment on the question for why.

Comment: Thanks again I found a small bug / mistake if I copy a text and paste it into the input text it does not work properly

Comment: @utdev: Does for me. What do you mean by "does not work properly"? *How* does it not work properly?

Comment: If I for example copy the word "name" into the input field and add 3 letters I do not get the *br* sign

Comment: @utdev: Then you've applied the above incorrectly. It definitely works above.